# Vue - build shows infinite loading tab

Tags: vue.js, apache, npm, vuetify.js

I have a tiny project with a bunch of images and vuetify.js library
Project works fine with `vue serve` or `npm run serve`

I then do `npm run build`, copy dist folder to my Raspberry Pi Zero v1.3 where it already runs a few other websites and they work fine

But when I open the built project in browser it just gives me infinite loading tab
Browser also throws "this tab is slowing down browser. Stop it?" kinda error

If I DO stop it I sometimes get this warning in console
"Script terminated by timeout at:" referring to chunk-vendors.js in FireFox or "RESULT_CODE_HUNG" in Chrome

Do I need to deploy code on the same computer I develop it on? Are there any spec requirements or do I need npm packages or something?

Also when I open the tab I can hear the fans in my PC speed up a bit if that helps

Also if I stop the tab the HTML structure is being shown but without images. Can that be the cause of this?

Comment: Do those other website also use a bunch of images? Loading a lot of images can be slow.

Comment: @Samball I wish it was that. By a "bunch" i meant like 10 or so, but just in case - I removed them all from code and the result is the same - app built by vue just refuses to show. Right now I'm using CDN libs approach of vue and vuetify and they work fine, but I'd like to do it the right way with cli and all that stuff

Answer (score 0):

What version of vuetify.js are you using, there was a bug before version 3 in the v-slider: https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/4746

Comment: I haven't used v-slider in my project, only v-row, v-col, v-card & v-img. How do I get the version of vuetify I downloaded? I don't see a version number in package.json

Comment: Oh, if I got it right it's Vuetify 2.6.4 according to /node_modules/vuetify/ folder

Comment: If updating doesn't resolve the issue there could be a recursive issue that makes the browser get stuck, but more of your code is required to spot that

Comment: For the lack of better answer I award this one the bounty. I just started from scratch and it now works for some reason. I think what happened was I *somehow* managed to add vuetify to Vue version 3 which is not supported afaik